# Is it possible to run the python script automatically from the same position where the connection lost?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, screen-scraping

How do I make a web scraping script that will run automatically from the same position where the connection lost?.

Let's suppose we run a scrapy web scraping script and we have to scrape 100 pages and after 50 pages suddenly I lost my internet connection.

So how can I modify my code to run again for the remaining  50 pages?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from books_crawler.items import BooksCrawlerItem


class BooksSpider(Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

        # process next page
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[text()="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=BooksCrawlerItem(), response=response)

        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//*[@class="price_color"]/text()').extract_first()

        image_urls = response.xpath('//img/@src').extract_first()
        image_urls = image_urls.replace('../..', 'http://books.toscrape.com/')

        l.add_value('title', title)
        l.add_value('price', price)
        l.add_value('image_urls', image_urls)

        return l.load_item()
```

Comment: I would think that this style of question is better suited over on the code review site

Comment: You could also enumerate Your pages and save the number to file every loop and if connection is lost read file and start from there.

Comment: +1 to what @Matiiss said. That's exactly how you'd do it. You've not shown any code which uses `start_urls`. In your case, you could save `absolute_next_page_url` to a text file _before_ it's processed so that if the connection drops, you read the text file and start from the URL in that file. Write the file in `'w'` mode (write) so that you're always overwriting it and can use that at the start of each session.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful for me.  @Matiiss

Answer (score 0):

You could make the function recursive. From what you posted I can't exactly see where in the script you would lose the connection, but using an if statement something like the code below:

```
If 'Connection is lost':
    return my_function()
```

If you then edit the code so that you keep track of on which page of the 100 pages you are, you can then give that to the function as a parameter and it will pick up where it left off. If losing the connection is connected to some kind of limit reached and having a timeout, you can also add a line of code so that you wait a few seconds before you try again.